# What is the UFW equivalant of the following iptables rules?

Tags: iptables, ufw

I'm trying to translate some iptables rules to UFW but struggling a little. I believe the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

would be:

```
ufw allow in on lo
```

I can't figure out the following two because I can't find a UFW equivalent to the "*!*" operator in iptables:

```
# Block remote packets claiming to be from a loopback address.  
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j DROP  
ip6tables -A INPUT -s ::1/128 ! -i lo -j DROP
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need the inversion operator? Why can't you simply block specified traffick rather than allow every but specified traffick? I think a small change in perspective might help you leverage the tools you already have.

As for an inversion operator in UFW, there does not appear to be one insofar as my Googling has returned.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @DevinM. Unfortunately I'm not savvy enough yet to know how I'd block access to the loopback interface from packets claiming to be localhost.